Attempt to read property "slug" on null
I'm encountering an issue in my Laravel application when I try to access the URL https://example.com/sitemaps.xml. The error message I receive is 'Attempt to read property "slug" on null'.
The error seems to be originating from the following line in my resources/views/default/sitemaps.blade.php file:
{{ url('category', [$subcategory->category->slug, $subcategory->slug]) }}

Can anyone help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it?

One of your subcategories doesn't have a category (or that category has been deleted).

try this
@if ($subcategory->category)
{{ url('category', [$subcategory->category->slug, $subcategory->slug]) }}
@endif

and make sure that $subcategory->category is not NULL

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The above error occurs when accessing the slug property from a null category object. Here are two possible solutions:
For PHP v8 or above
{{ url('category', [$subcategory->category?->slug, $subcategory->slug]) }}

For PHP v7 or above
@if ($subcategory->category)
    {{ url('category', [$subcategory->category->slug, $subcategory->slug]) }}
@endif

